# TSQL CASE SYNTAX END = nn

Tags: t-sql, syntax, case, cognos

I encountered the following code generated from COGNOS:

```
  CASE 
    WHEN CASE 
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL1'
                THEN 1
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL2'
                THEN 2
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL3'
                THEN 3
            ELSE 4
            END = 1
        THEN 'M'
    WHEN CASE 
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL1'
                THEN 1
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL2'
                THEN 2
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL3'
                THEN 3
            ELSE 4
            END = 2
        THEN 'Q'
    WHEN CASE 
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL1'
                THEN 1
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL2'
                THEN 2
            WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL3'
                THEN 3
            ELSE 4
            END = 3
        THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'T'
    END AS 'VAL4'
```

I cannot determine the significance of the '=' operators following 'END = nn'.  In addition, the CASE blocks seem to be duplicates that do not provide distinguishing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified further than @SpaceUser7448 this would look like:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL1' THEN 'M'
    WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL2' THEN 'Q'
    WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL3' THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'T'
END AS 'VAL4'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be clearer

```
 CASE 
   WHEN (
     CASE 
        WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL1' THEN 1
        WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL2' THEN 2
        WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL3' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
     END
   ) = 1 THEN 'M'

   WHEN (
     CASE 
       WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL1' THEN 1
       WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL2' THEN 2
       WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL3' THEN 3
       ELSE 4
     END 
   ) = 2 THEN 'Q'

   WHEN (
     CASE 
       WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL1' THEN 1
       WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL2' THEN 2
       WHEN 'FIELD1' LIKE 'VAL3' THEN 3
       ELSE 4
     END
   ) = 3 THEN 'Y'
   ELSE 'T'
 END AS 'VAL4'
```

Essentially the outer case has, for each of its 'when' options, another case case statement

So,

- if Field1 was 'VAL1' then the result would be 'M'
- if Field1 was 'VAL2' then the result would be 'Q'
- if Field1 was 'VAL3' then the result would be 'Y'

and if Field1 was anything else it would be 'T'

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Much obliged.

Comment: No problem.  If you are happy with the answer can you vote it up.